# How can i install the yarn package in an nginx:1.25 container

Tags: node.js, laravel, docker, nginx, yarnpkg

I have containerized my laravel project. However, I want to be able to run yarn commands on the web container(nginx:1.25 container). I have searched the internet, but haven't had success finding an answer.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.25

# Copy the Nginx configuration file
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Add yarn here

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /src
```

Comment: I'd use a separate container, maybe based on the `node` image (which would have Yarn preïnstalled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It differs from the base image you are using, for your case, nginx:1.25 is based on debian bookworm, so I recommend installing yarn using nvm and npm:

```
FROM nginx:1.25

# Copy the Nginx configuration file
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Add yarn here
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash \
    && source ~/.bashrc \
    && nvm install --lts \
    && npm install -g yarn


# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /src
```